# Mostrar log actualizado en la terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Estoy desarrollando con Django (2.2) en Ubuntu usando un servidor Apache. Cómo puedo mostrar, y que esté siempre actualizado, el registro de logs del servidor?

Al no usar `python manage.py runserver` no me aparecen los registros automáticamente en la terminal y, cada vez que quiero mirar los logs, tengo que cerrar y volver a abrir el archivo para verlo actualizado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para visualizar los ficheros de log de apache en tiempo real, yo lo que utilizo es

> tail -f ficherolog.log

... si quieres más de 10 líneas, puedes especificarlo con:

> tail -n 20 ficherolog.log

Si necesitas la terminal siempre puedes mandarlo a ejecutar en background y recuperarlo después.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el comando `tail` con el argumento `-f` que refrescará el archivo cada vez que éste cambie.

```sh
tail /var/logs/apache2/error_log -f
```